# Xcode - IB elements not shown in my view at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, uisegmentedcontrol

I've got a very weird problem with my iOS project. 
I have a UIViewController with some labels and buttons and when user enters this view I programmatically build a gameboard (it's the minesweeper game).
What I wanted to do now is add a simple element (in my case a segmented control but i tried also with a button and doesn't work) at the bottom or at the beginning of the board.

When I add something from the Interface Builder I can see that in the storyboard but when I run the app puff, it's disappeared!
View contains only the "old" elements and the new one is not shown.
Yes I made a IBOutlet:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *clickTypeSegmentedControl;
```

And yes I checked if references of segemented control are ok.
I can't really understand what is wrong, if someone can help I'll be very grateful.

** EDIT: I added code of the ViewController, there are some other methods I left out because they only handle the game. I repeat: even if I add a simple button with no actions, it will not be shown.

```
#import "GameViewController.h"
#import "GameBoardModel.h"
#import "ScoreViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]

@interface GameViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timerLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *bombsLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *restartButton;
@property(nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *soundEffects;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *clickTypeSegmentedControl;

@end

@implementation GameViewController
@synthesize difficulty, timer, playerName, scoreToAdd, clickTypeSegmentedControl;

double secondsPassed=-1.0f;
int seconds=0;
int totalRowsCols=0, totalMines=0, heightWidth=0, clicKNumber=0;

static NSString * const IMAGE_NAME_FLAG = @"flag.png";
static NSString * const IMAGE_NAME_BOMB_X = @"bomb.png";


- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Menù" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(popAlertAction:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=backButton;


    clickTypeSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;


    rootController = (BombsSeekerViewController *)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];


    NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    playerName = [defaults objectForKey:@"NomeGiocatore"];

    scoreToAdd = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    [self createGameBoard:difficulty];
    [self newGame:nil];


}


-(void) newGame:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.view.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    clicKNumber=0;
    secondsPassed=0;
    self.timerLabel.text = [self labelString:secondsPassed];

    self.game = [[Game alloc] initWithWidth:totalRowsCols AndHeight:totalRowsCols AndMineCount:totalMines];
    self.buttonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self.restartButton addTarget:self action:@selector(newGame:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:self.restartButton];
    [self.view addSubview:self.timerLabel];
    [self.view addSubview:self.bombsLabel];
    for(int i = 0; i < totalRowsCols; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < totalRowsCols; j++) {
            self.button = [[Tile alloc] initWithLocation: CGPointMake(j,i) andHW:heightWidth andBlock:self.game.board[j][i] andTag:(i*totalRowsCols+j)];
            [self.buttonArray addObject:self.button];
            [self.view addSubview:self.button];
            [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(click:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        }
    }

    [self.timer invalidate];
}


- (void) createGameBoard:(int)diff{
    switch (diff) {
        case 1:
            totalRowsCols = 6;
            totalMines = 2;
            heightWidth = 44;
            break;
        case 2:
            totalRowsCols = 8;
            totalMines = 16;
            heightWidth = 35;
            break;
        case 3:
            totalRowsCols = 10;
            totalMines = 25;
            heightWidth = 29;
            break;
    }
    self.flagCount = totalMines;
    _bombsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",self.flagCount];

}


-(NSString *) labelString: (int) num {
    if(num < 10) {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"00%i",num];
    }
    else if(self.timeCount.intValue < 100) {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%i",num];
    }
    else if(self.timeCount.intValue < 1000) {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",num];
    }
    else
        return @"---";
}

-(void) click:(Tile *)sender {
    if(clicKNumber <1){
        [self refreshLabel:self.timer];
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(refreshLabel:)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];
        clicKNumber++;

    }

    if(self.game.gameStatus == STATUS_LOST || self.game.gameStatus == STATUS_WON) return;
    if (self.clickTypeSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 && sender.block.marking == MARKING_BLANK) {
        [self.game clickedAtColumn: sender.point.x AndRow: sender.point.y];
        for(Tile *b in self.buttonArray) {
            if(b.block.marking == MARKING_CLICKED) {
                b.enabled = NO;
            }
            else if(b.block.marking == MARKING_BLANK) {
                [b setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [b setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
        }

    }
    else if (self.clickTypeSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){
        if(sender.block.marking == MARKING_BLANK && self.flagCount > 0) {
            sender.block.marking = MARKING_FLAGGED;
            self.flagCount--;
             _bombsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",self.flagCount];
            [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:IMAGE_NAME_FLAG] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else if(sender.block.marking == MARKING_FLAGGED) {
            sender.block.marking = MARKING_BLANK;
            self.flagCount++;
             _bombsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",self.flagCount];
            [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tile.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }

    if(self.game.gameStatus == STATUS_LOST) [self gameLost:sender];
    else if(self.game.gameStatus == STATUS_WON) [self gameWon];

}
```

Comment: you really need to show more code if you really need a solution.

Comment: what code I'm supposed to show?
I know there's no code but it's because till yesterday I was able to add items to my view and saw them, suddenly today this not work.
So maybe it could be some settings or other, but it is not connected with the gameboard because even if I insert an item to the top of the page attached to a label this is not shown.

Comment: Hmm strange indeed, still... post your code! Or a screenshot of the storyboard. Maybe your scene is not connected or something. Just give us intel.

Comment: I posted code of the  ViewController, unfortunately i can't post images yet!

Comment: Please check my answer. Thanks for putting more code up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is what I think it is, you should not be doing this:

```
[self.view.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

When the `viewDidLoad` is called, the `newGame` method is called, which removes al subviews from Superview. Including the ones added in Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure controller in storyboard is linked with the right controller class.

Comment: You mean the "Class" in the Identity inspector? That is correct I checked it right now

Comment: I didn't understand your scenario very well but if you added the controls in storyboard then check if the new one are on top of old ones in interface builder (check the Document Outline to see the tree). I presume old controls are still visible.

Comment: Use hidden property instead of removing the view from hierarchy ([UIView removeFromSuperview]) may temporary fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You call this method during `-viewDidLoad:`

```
-(void) newGame:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.view.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    //...
}
```

Thus, anything you put in your nib is getting removed after it loads.